# How do I include external library phar file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have couple of library phar files, where do I include those in laravel 5 application?

So far what I tried is created a folder under `vendor` directory and added the phar files I needed and finally included them in the `vendor/autoload.php` file as below.

```
// Include internal library
include(__DIR__.'/internal/composer/vendor/autoload.php');
require('phar://'.__DIR__.'/internal/Common.phar/index.php');
require('phar://'.__DIR__.'/internal/client.phar/index.php');
```

This is working, but the issue is when ever you do composer update, the `autoload.php` file get override.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a folder outside `vendor` and copied the phar files there and finally edited the composer.json file as following to include the phar files.

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": ...,
        "psr-4": ...,
        "files" : [
            "extension/internal/client.phar",
            "extension/internal/Common.phar",
            "extension/internal/composer/vendor/autoload.php"]
    }
```